# Save a rails console session to disk and reload later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tmux

I have a rails console session in a tmux session, and it's taking up a lot of memory. It has a lot of data, pretty deeply nested, in a few variables, and it took a long time to query for that data, so right now my plan is to serialize the data and save it to a file. That way, I can reload it later and not take up too much memory on the machine while I'm not using it. I'm wondering, though, if there's a better way. Is it possible for me to save my whole rails console session and load it up again later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't save a whole Rails console session (the same is true for a simple `irb` session) for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Create, or edit your `~/.irbrc` file to include:

```
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 200
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-history"
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking this saves the commands, but not the data?

Comment: @Qaz AFAIK yes, you are.